# How to share a directory on the VM as a disk with my host with virtual machine manager

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I've been using ssfsh on my host box to connect to a local vm running in linux virtual machine manager. However I have found it to be really slow and am exploring using NFS. However this seems like over kill and I was wondering if I could just share a directory on the VM as a disk with my host with simple settings from VM manager.

thanks

Comment: Which Hypervisor are you using ? KVM ? LXC ? Xen ?

Comment: @Lawrence KVM is the one.